# iOS TableView Multiline text

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have this table and I want the lines to be multiline text.
How can I achieve this? This is the way I read everywhere.
This is my code to setup my cells:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SchoolCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredSchools[indexPath.row].name
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = schools[indexPath.row].name
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = ColorsPlus.instance.VLDMediumBlue()
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "TitilliumWeb-Regular", size: 16.0)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = ColorsPlus.instance.VLDDarkBlue()
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

[image: Wrong..]

Comment: UITableviewAutomatic dimension

Comment: have a look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 0):

Add UITableViewCell in your tableView in storyboard.

Set number of lines equal to zero in interface builder. You are setting after cell has been instantiated and height already been calculated.

You should have autolayout enabled and constraints setup for the label, enough to determine the height of cell. In your case, set top, bottom , left and right constraint.

Set tableView.height = UITableviewAutomatic;

This should result in multi-line text with dynamic cell height.

---

Or if you are not interested in dynamic cell height, then simply increase UITableCellView height in tableView Delegate

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

    return 60.0;
```

}

or simply update the default height as below

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 60.0
```